# Firefox 10 DOM issues with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, firefox

Has anybody else been noticing odd issues with the DOM structure in Firefox 10?

In the last 10 days, I've had a series of failures using a number of jQuery plugins in which the object data is unretrievable because the data is not where it's supposed to be.

Forgive me if my terminology here is incorrect.

Go to http://www.phiairmedical.com in Firefox 10 and open up Firebug Console. Roll over any of the navigation and you will see a failure "opts is undefined" (line 101 of jquery.cycle.min.js)

Looking at that line, it's trying to retrieve stored data ('cycle.opts'), but it clearly isn't finding it.

Last week, I had a similar problem using jScrollPane in which the api functions stored in the data object were unretrievable. What I discovered was that by changing the specification pushing and retrieving, I was able to access it.

The recommendation with jScrollPane was to push the data like this:

```
apis.push($(this).jScrollPane().data('jsp'));
```

And I call the function like this:

```
$.each(apis, function(i) { 
  this.destroy(); 
 });
```

That is what works everywhere else. To accommodate FF10 I had to do it like this:

```
apis.push($(this).jScrollPane().data('data.jsp'));
```

and change this.destroy() to

```
this.jsp.destroy();
```

I believe the current problem with the site linked above is the same issue as it was perfectly fine when I launched it last summer. Now, the navigation rollovers don't work because the Cycle plugin is failing with this data issue.

I'm hoping someone can shed some light as to whether they've experienced this or heard about it or how to go about submitting a bug to Firefox (if that's what it is).

**EDIT:**
To test this out, I went in and changed line 100 in jquery.cycle.min.js from:

```
var opts = $(cont).data('cycle.opts');
```

to

```
var opts = $(cont).data('data.cycle.opts');
```

And the problem is eliminated.

Comment: And this is why jQuery plugins are low quality and non robust. Learn your lesson, use robust code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of this problem turned out to be the FireQuery extension in Firebug. It had nothing to do with the quality of the code.

With FireQuery disabled, the original code ran without errors.

Further testing lead me to find that I could leave FireQuery enabled by unchecking the "Show internal jQuery data" option, though this option is actually recommended by the developer when using jQuery 1.7.1 in order to view internal data.

[Binary FireQuery FAQ](http://firequery.binaryage.com/#faq)